# vuejs history mode routing issue with routing parameters, asp.net core and SignalR backend

Tags: vue.js, signalr

I am using a VueJS frontend with vue-router and a SignalR ASP.NET Core backend.

Now i want the ability to have my Clients connect to a room, and send data to only members of that group. I do that by with two methods on my backend, one to create a room and  send them a 12char long randomly generated string stored in-memory, or by joining a group, sending one of these strings as parameter for the Join Room method. Now, this works fine but i also want the ability to join over a link with the group ID string appended to the url. That would be `myurl.com/room/:groupId` which i planned to implement by routing to the same component but in the latter case having a prop set with the url paramter `:groupId`. This does work and in the dialog where you usually enter this groupId, it is correctly displayed.

Anyhow, i do get the following error messages in DevTools when navigating to `myurl.com/room/:groupId`:
`Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Now i think that has something to do with my backend configuration, inside my Startup.cs, i have pasted this code from somewhere to circumvent the problem with getting 404s on every path that isnt "/":

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseRouting();
      app.UseDefaultFiles();
      app.UseStaticFiles();


      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        Console.WriteLine(endpoints.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
        endpoints.MapHub<DraftHub>("/drafthub");
      });

      //this function right here is what i mean, it sends index.html after assembling the path with vue-router i suppose?
      app.Run( async (context) =>
        {
          context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
          await context.Response.SendFileAsync(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath,"index.html"));
      });

    }
```

So i am wondering, does that error mean, that the SignalR negotiation is failing because the resposne is text/html and not text/json? If that were the case, then why does the negotiation not fail when i navigate to the url `myurl.com/room` without the groupId appended to it? it uses the same fallback `await context.Response.SendFileAsync(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath,"index.html"));`? Note that both paths are routing to the exact same Component in my frontend, just the one with the groupId in the URL passes it as a prop and therefore sets it as a default value.

Here the Code of the component.

```
<template>
  <base-view>
    <join-dialog
      v-model="visible"
      :login-info.sync="loginInfo"
      @click:create="createRoom"
      @click:join="joinRoom"
    />
    <chat-sidebar
      :users="connectionInfo.groupConnections"
      :my-name="loginInfo.userName"
      :user="loginInfo.userName"
      :group-id="connectionInfo.groupId"
    />
  </base-view>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, Ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
import JoinDialog from "@/components/JoinDialog.vue";
import ChatSidebar from "@/components/ChatSidebar.vue";
import ChessBoard from "@/components/Chess/ChessBoard.vue";
import {
  sendCreateRoom,
  onUpdateRoom,
  ConnectionInfo,
  sendJoinRoom,
  start,
} from "@/service/signalr/draftHub";
import { createLoginInfo } from "../service/models";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    JoinDialog,
    ChatSidebar,
    ChessBoard,
  },
  props: {
    groupId: {      // THIS HERE IS SET WHEN URL HAS GROUP ID IN IT.
      type: String,
      default: () => "",
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const visible = ref(true);
    const loginInfo = ref(createLoginInfo());

    loginInfo.value.groupId = props.groupId; //ALREADY SET THE GROUP ID INCASE IT WAS IN THE URL

    const connectionInfo: Ref<ConnectionInfo> = ref({});

    const createRoom = () => {
      sendCreateRoom(loginInfo.value.userName).then(
        () => (visible.value = false)
      );
    };

    const joinRoom = () => {
      sendJoinRoom(loginInfo.value).then(() => (visible.value = false));
    };

    onUpdateRoom((connInfo: ConnectionInfo) => {
      connectionInfo.value = connInfo;
      console.log("running handler now to update users", connInfo);
    });

    start().then(() => console.log("connected to drafthub"));

    return {
      visible,
      createRoom,
      joinRoom,
      loginInfo,
      connectionInfo,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

And here, my vue-router Setup:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import PrivateRoom from "../views/PrivateRoom.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue"),
  },
  {
    path: "/room",
    name: "PrivateRoom",
    component: PrivateRoom,
  },
  {
    path: "/room/:groupId",
    name: "PrivateRoomInstance",
    component: PrivateRoom,
    props: true,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

I hope i did not leave out any important information. Please call me out if i did so and thank you very much for any kind of response, i would already be more than grateful to just be pointed in the correct direction, since i dont even have a clue if its a router issue or a signalr issue.

In case anyone wants to take a deeper look i will leave both of the github links, to the  [frontend](https://github.com/Tomtommytomtom/chess-game-frontend) and [backend](https://github.com/Tomtommytomtom/chess-game-backend)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the reason for this appearing was, the path for my SignalR hub was, "/drafthub".
For some reason going to the frontent path "/room" (without appended "/") would send the negotiation request to the correct path, anyhow, as soon as i had "/room/", it would send it to the path "/room/drafthub", which the server responded with my default 404 fallback, my index.html which then used clientside routing. So in essence, it served that twice, once when i typed in the URL, and another time when i tried to upgrade to the signalR connection.

**FIX**:

i am still trying to figure out what exactly maps this to "/room/drafthub" but for now i just also mapped the Drafthub to that endpoint in the `ConfigureServices` Method in my backend like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapHub<DraftHub>("/drafthub");
        endpoints.MapHub<DraftHub>("/room/drafthub");
      });
```