# Vue router behavior from localhost vs. on the web host server

Tags: .net, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'd like to ask some specifics and good explanation about the vue router behavior between the localhost and after deployed to the web host server.
First off, here's my sample router code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
...

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        ...,
        {
            path: '/Home/Details/:id',         
            name: 'contentDetails',
            component: ContentDetails
        },
         ]
});
```

The router works fine when pushing a component into another component and that's not what I'm referring to. I'm referring to when you
intentionally reloads the browser after the router navigated from one path to another. Let's say after I navigated to one of my path
**`http://localhost:8080/Home/Details/906776`** in my local machine and then I force to reload the browser it works fine. On the other hand, after I deployed my project
into the webhost server, when I navigate to the same url **`http://mydomain_name/Home/Details/906776`** from the web host server, and then reload the browser, it can't be reloaded.
When I check it, this line of code **this.contId = this.$route.params.id;** is **undefined** but it's not in my localhost. Why?  Any thoughts of this? I appreciate
any alternative suggestions to make the browser reload to work from the web host server if possible. Thanks

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: I guess it's not doable in my end since I'm using .net core which doesn't have web.config for the IIS Url rewrite. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Probably that's the other way around but not sure about 'Adding the File' thing since .Net Core uses applicationsettings.json instead of the web.config. But the most crucial part on web.config example is this line  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />

Comment: Note sure what should I supply here "{REQUEST_FILENAME}"

Comment: can you share iis configuration? Here is a possibly related q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139221/vuejs-history-mode-routing-issue-with-routing-parameters-asp-net-core-and-signa

Comment: @Daniel - it has nothing to do with IIS, the mode: 'history' in the vue doc only works with localhost when u are using router but not in the web host server because for whatever reason the value of $route.params.id in the web host will be cleared out if u reload or open the path in new tab. The best way to go is by using props if u want to get the param value of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried receiving the /:id as a prop on the ContentDetails component?
You could try changing /:id to /:contId
And than on the props of ContentDetails

```
{
 contId: {required:true}
}
```

Instead of having it as a data property.

Comment: I didn't use /:id as a prop to ContentDetails component I just use the this.$route.params.id to get the value of the id from the path and then assign it to the contId data property of the ContentDetails.

Comment: Not sure why it works fine in the localhost but not on the deployed server. the this.$route.params.id will become undefine when u console it but not in the local host

Comment: I tried to console it both in created() and mounted() hook and it's undefine but not in my localhost.

Comment: Is this contId: {required:true} from the data property when u declared them? because in my case I declared it this way as an integer data(){return { conId: 0 }}

Comment: when you have :variable on the router it is being passed on the props of the component you referenced on the route. Without using this.$route.params.id. So you wouldn't need to declare on the data or wherever.

Comment: Here is an example
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html
Where the component receive the router parameter in the props

Comment: Thanks leonardo, you got it right!..It's way better to go props than route.params to get the parameter value of the route path. Good suggestions!...I'll make your post an answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped